# Failed to load view state error from web user control

Tags: c#, radgrid

I have set some default properties for Telerik RadGrid like sorting etc. in web user control.and then use this user control on aspx page.Grid shows data perfectly,but when i click on sorting it gives the following error.

```
Failed to load viewstate. The control tree into which viewstate is being loaded must match the control tree that was used to save viewstate during the previous request. For example, when adding controls dynamically, the controls added during a post-back must match the type and position of the controls added during the initial request.
```

Here is my user control code.

```
  [ToolboxData("<{0}:CustomRadGrid runat=server> </{0}:CustomRadGrid>")]
    public class CustomRadGrid : RadGrid
    {


        RadGrid radgrid;
        public override bool AllowSorting
        {
            get
            {
                bool o = Convert.ToBoolean(ViewState["Text"]);
                return radgrid.AllowSorting != false ? true : true;
            }
            set
            {
                EnsureChildControls();
                if (value != null)
                {
                    ViewState["Text"] = value;
                }
            }
        }
        protected override void CreateChildControls()
         {
             Controls.Clear();
            radgrid = new RadGrid();
            //radgrid.AllowSorting = true;
            radgrid.AllowFilteringByColumn = true;
            radgrid.Width = Unit.Percentage(100);
            radgrid.ExportSettings.ExportOnlyData = true;
            radgrid.ExportSettings.Excel.Format = GridExcelExportFormat.ExcelML;
            this.Controls.Add(radgrid);
        }




        public CustomRadGrid()
        {
            //
            // TODO: Add constructor logic here
            //
        }
    }
```

Control is add in aspx:

```
<customRadGrid:CustomRadGrid runat="server" ID="sa" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" AllowSorting="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false"> 
    <MasterTableView> 
        <Columns> 
              <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="EmpID" HeaderText="Employeeid ID">  
              </telerik:GridBoundColumn> <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>                
              <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Salary" HeaderText="Salary"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        </Columns> 
    </MasterTableView> 
</customRadGrid:CustomRadGrid>
```

I have tried everything to solve this problem,please help if anybody have an idea.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you add this control dynamically and where you add it.

Comment: I simply add it at aspx page,i mean not dynamically.

Comment: <customRadGrid:CustomRadGrid runat="server" ID="sa" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" AllowSorting="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
         <MasterTableView>
              <Columns>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="EmpID" HeaderText="Employeeid ID"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                 <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                 <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Salary" HeaderText="Salary"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                  </Columns>
         </MasterTableView>
     </customRadGrid:CustomRadGrid>

Comment: do you try to add EnableViewState="false" to your grid

Comment: yes,when I set EnableViewState="fasle".it gives following error.Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.ArrayList' to type 'System.Collections.Hashtable'

Comment: ok this is another error debug it and see why this is shown.